# Access the updated value after Set state in React

Tags: reactjs, events, jsx, react-state

The component renders the sum , which was calculated by previous values.

I know how batches work and why is this. I could solve this by implementing a button and connect the button to a click event handler , but I would like to calculate the sum with onChange Event inside the calculate() funciton .

So I would like to handle the set state and the calculation process in the same function.

So my quiestion is how could I get the updated value of num1 and num2 , which was updated in the same batch:

```
setSum(parseFloat(**Updated**num1) + parseFloat(**Updated**num2))
```

--

```
export default function Home() {
  const [num1 , SetNum1] = useState(0.0)
  const [num2 , setNum2] = useState(0.0)
  const [sum, setSum] = useState(0.0)


  const calculate = (e) => {
    switch(e.target.id){
      case 'num1':
        SetNum1((prev) => {
          return e.target.value
        })
        break;
      case 'num2':
        setNum2((prev) => {
          return e.target.value
        })
        break;
    }
    setSum(parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="number" className="form-control"  id="num1" value={num1} onChange={(e) => calculate(e)}  />
        <input type="number" className="form-control"  id="num2" value={num2} onChange={(e) => calculate(e)}  />
        Sum : {sum}
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is it possible to access the most recent num1 value after SetNum1 or I have to implement a button which calculates the sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to listen for changes with `useEffect`.

```
export default function Home() {
  const [num1 , setNum1] = useState(0.0)
  const [num2 , setNum2] = useState(0.0)
  const [sum, setSum] = useState(0.0)


  // execute the function whe num1 or num2 is changed
  useEffect(() => {
    setSum(parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2))
  }, [num1, num2]);

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="number" className="form-control"  id="num1" value={num1} onChange={(e) => setNum1(e.target.value)}  />
        <input type="number" className="form-control"  id="num2" value={num2} onChange={(e) => setNum2(e.target.value)}  />
        Sum : {sum}
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to keep the sum in state. Because it is derived from the two other state variables, you can and should just calculate it on each render:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Home() {
  const [num1 , SetNum1] = useState(0.0)
  const [num2 , setNum2] = useState(0.0)
  const sum = parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2)


  const calculate = (e) => {
    switch(e.target.id){
      case 'num1':
        SetNum1((prev) => {
          return e.target.value
        })
        break;
      case 'num2':
        setNum2((prev) => {
          return e.target.value
        })
        break;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="number" className="form-control"  id="num1" value={num1} onChange={(e) => calculate(e)}  />
        <input type="number" className="form-control"  id="num2" value={num2} onChange={(e) => calculate(e)}  />
        Sum : {sum}
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is the simplest and most efficient solution. No useEffect() needed either.

Here is more explanation and a runnable example: https://react.dev/learn/choosing-the-state-structure#avoid-redundant-state